# Posting a question not possible: "Error occured submitting the question"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, quality-filter

I would like to post the following post on stackoverflow, but I always receive this message in a red box: "Error occured submitting the question." No idea what to do to solve it, there are no boxes with some information about the mistake.

> Hi,
>
> I have been coding a site that's working great in Firefox, Chrome and
>   Safari. But in IE, it's not showing up right at all. This is the
>   demoversion of the website: http://demo.wiperstimes.be">Wipers Times
>
> **1: IE9 — IE11**
>
> I inserted following code for MQ in IE: 
>        But
>   not all the MQ are working.
>   - There's a MQ at 1024px, for a max-width of the body, but IE9-11 ignores this MQ.
>   **CSS**
>       @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) { body { width: 1024px;}
>
> - IE9-11 doesn't show up the right footer on a desktop screen:
> - On the homepage, there are 2 columns that has to be next to each other:
>     **HTML**
>
> **CSS**
>       @media screen and (min-width: 769px) {      .index_links {   margin-top: 40px;   padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;   width:45%;   float:
>   left;   background-color:#C7C7C7; } .index_rechts {   margin-top:
>   40px;   padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;   width: 45%;   float: right;
>   background-color:#C7C7C7; } }
>
> - Footer: The footer for small devices is showing up on desktop screens (with 'logo: display: none')
>     **HTML**
>        
>                     
>     **CSS**
>     @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {     .footercolumn_logo {   display: inline;   padding-right: 40%; }  .footercolumn {   width:
>     17%;   display: inline-block;   text-align: left;   margin-top: 20px;
>     } }
>
> **1: IE6 — IE8** It looks like everything's going wrong: 
>   - The whole site is left-aligned, but it has to be center-aligned.
>   - The header is not as long as the body. 
>   - The menu-items aren't next to each other on one line
>   - The two footer columns are showing up on top of each other (nowhere defined)
>
> I don't know where to start with solving these problems.  Is there a
>   mistake in the head of my HTML?
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="nl"> <head> <title>Wipers Times / Vakantiewoning te Ieper</title> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta
> ```
>
> name="description" content="Wipers Times>
>
> http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700'
>   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
>       http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rufina' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
>
> </script>

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple problems with your post:

- Don't use *Hi* and *Thanks*; these are just noise; we like to focus on the content itself.
- You didn't format your code blocks; see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to indent the blocks so we can read them.
- Your demo version link isn't working; better to use Markdown syntax for linking; `[link text](url to link to)` for the inline version. Your link is neither HTML nor Markdown.

Your post should look like:

```
I have been coding a site that's working great in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.
But in IE, it's not showing up right at all. This is the demoversion of the website: [Wipers Times](http://demo.wiperstimes.be)    

**1: IE9 — IE11**

I inserted following code for MQ in IE: 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js">

    </script>

But not all the MQ are working.

- There's a MQ at 1024px, for a max-width of the body, but IE9-11 ignores this MQ.

    **CSS**

        @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
        body {
        width: 1024px;}

- IE9-11 doesn't show up the right footer on a desktop screen:

- On the homepage, there are 2 columns that has to be next to each other:

    **HTML**

        <div class="index_links">
        <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="index_rechts">
        <p></p>
        </div>

    **CSS**

        @media screen and (min-width: 769px) {     
        .index_links {
          margin-top: 40px;
          padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
          width:45%;
          float: left;
          background-color:#C7C7C7;
        }
        .index_rechts {
          margin-top: 40px;
          padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
          width: 45%;
          float: right;
          background-color:#C7C7C7;
        }
        }

- Footer: The footer for small devices is showing up on desktop screens (with 'logo: display: none')

    **HTML**

        <footer>
          <div class="footercolumn_logo">
            <img class="footer_logo" src="images/logo/logo_wiperstimes.png" alt=""/>
          </div>
          <div class="footercolumn">
          </div>
          <div class="footercolumn">
          </div>
        </footer>

    **CSS**

        @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {    
        .footercolumn_logo {
          display: inline;
          padding-right: 40%;
        } 
        .footercolumn {
          width: 17%;
          display: inline-block;
          text-align: left;
          margin-top: 20px;
        }
        }  

**2: IE6 — IE8**

It looks like everything's going wrong: 

- The whole site is left-aligned, but it has to be center-aligned.
- The header is not as long as the body. 
- The menu-items aren't next to each other on one line
- The two footer columns are showing up on top of each other (nowhere defined)

I don't know where to start with solving these problems. 
Is there a mistake in the head of my HTML?

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
    <title>Wipers Times / Vakantiewoning te Ieper</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Wipers Times>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css?css=styles/html5reset-1.6.1.v.1344884364" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rufina' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/helper.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/responsiveslides.min2.js"></script>

     <!-- Media Queries -->
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile-nav.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px)">

        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 769px)">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen">
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
        <script src="js/selectivizr-1.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

which would render as:

> I have been coding a site that's working great in Firefox, Chrome and
>   Safari. But in IE, it's not showing up right at all. This is the demoversion of the website: [Wipers Times](http://demo.wiperstimes.be)
>
> **1: IE9 — IE11**
>
> I inserted following code for MQ in IE:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js">
>
> </script>
> ```
>
> But not all the MQ are working.
>
> - There's a MQ at 1024px, for a max-width of the body, but IE9-11 ignores this MQ.
>
>   **CSS**
>
>   ```
>   @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
>   body {
>   width: 1024px;}
>   ```
> - IE9-11 doesn't show up the right footer on a desktop screen:
> - On the homepage, there are 2 columns that has to be next to each other:
>
>   **HTML**
>
>   ```
>   <div class="index_links">
>   <p></p>
>   </div>
>   <div class="index_rechts">
>   <p></p>
>   </div>
>   ```
>
>   **CSS**
>
>   ```
>   @media screen and (min-width: 769px) {     
>   .index_links {
>     margin-top: 40px;
>     padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
>     width:45%;
>     float: left;
>     background-color:#C7C7C7;
>   }
>   .index_rechts {
>     margin-top: 40px;
>     padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
>     width: 45%;
>     float: right;
>     background-color:#C7C7C7;
>   }
>   }
>   ```
> - Footer: The footer for small devices is showing up on desktop screens (with 'logo: display: none')
>
>   **HTML**
>
>   ```
>   <footer>
>     <div class="footercolumn_logo">
>       <img class="footer_logo" src="images/logo/logo_wiperstimes.png" alt=""/>
>     </div>
>     <div class="footercolumn">
>     </div>
>     <div class="footercolumn">
>     </div>
>   </footer>
>   ```
>
>   **CSS**
>
>   ```
>   @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {    
>   .footercolumn_logo {
>     display: inline;
>     padding-right: 40%;
>   } 
>   .footercolumn {
>     width: 17%;
>     display: inline-block;
>     text-align: left;
>     margin-top: 20px;
>   }
>   }
>   ```
>
> **2: IE6 — IE8**
>
> It looks like everything's going wrong:
>
> - The whole site is left-aligned, but it has to be center-aligned.
> - The header is not as long as the body.
> - The menu-items aren't next to each other on one line
> - The two footer columns are showing up on top of each other (nowhere defined)
>
> I don't know where to start with solving these problems.  Is there a
>   mistake in the head of my HTML?
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="nl">
> <head>
> <title>Wipers Times / Vakantiewoning te Ieper</title>
> <meta charset="utf-8" />
> <meta name="description" content="Wipers Times>
>   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
>   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
> <!--[if lt IE 9]>
> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
> <![endif]-->
>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css?css=styles/html5reset-1.6.1.v.1344884364" />
>     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
>     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rufina' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
> <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/respond.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="javascript/plugins.js"></script>
> <script src="javascript/helper.js"></script>
> <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
> <script src="javascript/responsiveslides.min2.js"></script>
>
>  <!-- Media Queries -->
>   <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile-nav.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px)">
>
>   <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 769px)">
>
>   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen">
>   <![endif]-->
>
>   <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
>   <script src="js/selectivizr-1.0.3.min.js"></script>
>   <![endif]-->
> </head>
> ```